How to expand param list in C preprocessor
I have this macro:
#define DO_SOMETHING(N, a,b,c,...)

my goal is to write such macro with listsd (eg without ...) that expands to:
DO_SOMETHING(1, a,b,c,...) DO_SOMETHING(2, a,b,c,...) DO_SOMETHING(3, a,b,c,...)

Here's my approach:
#define REP_3(D, A) D(1, A) D(2, A) D(3, A) 
#define GENERATE(a,b,c, ...) REP_3(DO_SOMETHING, (a,b,c,__VA_ARGS__))

however, this expands to:
DO_SOMETHING(1, (a,b,c,...)) DO_SOMETHING(2, (a,b,c,...)) DO_SOMETHING(3, (a,b,c,...))

Perhaps, I need something like:
REP_3(DO_SOMETHING2, (a,b,c,__VA_ARGS__))
#define DO_SOMETHING2(N, A) DO_SOMETHING(N, unroll(A)) //??

How can I unroll that list of args represented by A? In other words, what's DO_SOMETHING2 should be defined to translate N, A, where A is a list of args (a,b,c,...) to N, a,b,c, ...
I could define unroll:
#define unroll(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define DO_SOMETHING2(N, A) DO_SOMETHING(N, unroll A)

but this doesn't work, or works with some changes in msvc, but not with gcc

This looks like an XY problem. Why do you need to use these macros? Why can't you use C functions, and let the compiler inline them?

@thebusybee complex 3rd party lib overloaded with huge amount of macro code that I need to update/modify. That's not to be changed anyways.

it's not and XY problem. I really do want to know how to do EXACTLY what I described in the question. I've solved it using one approach, but I wanted to update my solution with param lists

This is the change in question, with param lists IC_BITUNPACK_REP32 would change to D(0, A)... instead of D(0, __VA_ARGS__).... I'm pretty sure with boost.preprocessor I could that all in not time

Sorry, if the question wasn't worded clearly, but the goal was to:

#define REP_3(D, A) using lists (eg without ...) so that it would
expand and pass all the args to DO_SOMETHING macro prepending them with N

that is:
#define REP_3(D, A) D(1, A) D(2, A) D(3, A) 
#define DO_SOMETHING(N, a,b,c,...)
#define GENERATE(a,b,c, ...) REP_3(DO_SOMETHING, (a,b,c,__VA_ARGS__))

calling GENERATE(a,b,c,d,e) should expand to:
DO_SOMETHING(1, a,b,c,d,e) DO_SOMETHING(2, a,b,c,d,e) DO_SOMETHING(3, a,b,c,d,e)

In other words, what GENERATE(a,b,c, ...) should be defined to, without making changes to REP_3 and DO_SOMETHING?
At first, DO_SOMETHING should be passed as a list arg:
#define GENERATE(a,b,c, ...) REP_3(CALLFUNC, (DO_SOMETHING,a,b,c,__VA_ARGS__))

Then:
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define UNROLL(...)          __VA_ARGS__
#define CALLFUNC2(N, F, ...) EXPAND(F(N, __VA_ARGS__))
#define CALLFUNC1(...)       EXPAND(CALLFUNC2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define CALLFUNC(N, A)       CALLFUNC1(N, UNROLL A)

these multiple hoops through EXPAND are required to get msvc and gcc produce identical results: https://godbolt.org/z/cMxWsox74

Try this:
#define REP_3(D, ...) D(1, __VA_ARGS__) D(2, __VA_ARGS__) D(3, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define GENERATE(a,b,c, ...) REP_3(DO_SOMETHING, a,b,c,__VA_ARGS__)

This does require having at least one argument to GENERATE (trying to use #define GENERATE(...)... won't work).  You can fix that in gcc/clang by using the gcc extension adding a ## before each use of __VA_ARGS__.

I think this doesn’t work with ms compiler, but this is easy to workaround (or conformant preprocessor setting could be used). In my case, it’s already implemented this way. However, I specifically wanted to rewrite using a list of args

https://godbolt.org/z/9n6KfMMEn that's what I already had, the point was to  rewrite it with lists (Note, msvc version works, but apparently godbolt doesn't handle it correctly)

rewrite it with lists what is a "list" in the contxt of C preprocessor? In msvc, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor?view=msvc-170 .

by lists I was referring to tuples in boost preprocessor speak: (a, b, c, d), for preprocessor it looks like a single arg
